# I have loaded data into Searchable Spinner from firestore but filtering the results of searchablespinner is crashing my app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-spinner

The data from my firestore database has been successfully loaded into my searchable spinner but upon trying to filter my items(i.e., upon searching through the searchable spinner), my app is getting crashed. [First Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTP9.jpg)

From the above image we can clearly see that searchable spinner is getting populated from my cloud firestore database.

Until this point everything works fine, data is getting properly loaded from firestore and everything seems to be performing well until [Second Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40SFv.jpg)

As soon as i type my first letter in the searchview of the searchable spinner my app gets crashed as shown in the above screenshot

CODE:

```
parties=new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(cartActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parties);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    searchableSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    db.collection("/RootCollection/partyDocument/partyCollection")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:queryDocumentSnapshots){
                            partyMaster pm=documentSnapshot.toObject(partyMaster.class);
                            parties.add(pm.getName());
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            /*Object objectName=documentSnapshot.get("name");
                            String partyName=objectName.toString();
                            parties.add(partyName);*/
                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(cartActivity.this,"Error ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

This part i got from verbose of logcat indicating that there is a null pointer exception(But i have properly initialized my arraylist)

LOGCAT:

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-11 15:58:42.244 8801-8801/com.example.user1.salesmanapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user1.salesmanapp, PID: 8801
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:737)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:860)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:6749)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:50)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.publishResults(ArrayAdapter.java:546)
    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Are you getting the data correctly? And I'm not seeing where your adding the new list to the arrayadapter, your just calling notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Post your full adapter code and your searchview code

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to populate the adapter with a list that is empty because you are not adding or setting the parties list again to the adapter.

You can use the following code:

```
    db.collection("/RootCollection/partyDocument/partyCollection")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    parties=new ArrayList<>();
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:queryDocumentSnapshots){
                            partyMaster pm=documentSnapshot.toObject(partyMaster.class);
                            parties.add(pm.getName());

                    }

                    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(cartActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parties);

                    arrayAdapter.
               setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    searchableSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(cartActivity.this,"Error ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```